# Security using AJAX and set innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xss, innerhtml

Consider the following circumstances:

- I send an AJAX request (no user input) to PHP which starts a function.
- The function returns a string of raw HTML. Could be anything - a list of links, a bunch of empty divs, SVGs to insert inline, most of a page... No user input data is used in its creation.
- I receive the string as a response and insert it into a
  div.
- I'm (currently and would ideally like to continue) using **pure JS - no libraries**.

Accepting that some level of insecurity is inherent in JS, how insecure is what I've just done?

The [OWASP XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) says to escape all 'untrusted data'. Is the result of my AJAX request untrusted given the above circumstances? Is the result of any AJAX request regarded as 'untrusted'?

Is inserting HTML this way bad practice? If so what should I be doing instead?

**Edit to clarify a couple of things:**

- URL variables in the AJAX request are only used to start a PHP function on the server. No variables are passed to that function at all (specifically, I'm using Joomla's com_ajax component).
- *All* of the returned code is static and written by me.

Comment: Assuming the HTML returned by the server is entirely generated by you, and doesn't involve any user input, this sounds secure to me.

Comment: If you trust your programmer who wrote the server script, then you should trust the response.

Comment: Replace < and > with "" and use bbcode instead

Comment: Before sending the AJAX request you need to validate it with JAVASCRIPT whether there are values are not.

Comment: @SathvikCheela why before sending instead of after receiving on server-side?? I could see doing both, but the client-side portion isn't going to make anything more secure, it's just for quicker client-feedback.

Comment: My problem (knowing nothing about XSS) was thinking that AJAX might be vulnerable to DOM-based attacks even in the absence of explicit user input, and wondering how on Earth that was any different to a normal page load. From what I've read since XSS attacks are purely reliant on user input, so any static HTML or other known quantity returned from a server should be completely safe; would this be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the response is truly static and does not involve user input *of any kind*, this is fine. AJAX itself (as you hinted) does not make it vulnerable to XSS (as long as transport is secure, which practically means https).

One caveat (not necessarily in your case, but in general) could be what you consider user input and what not. Your application *always* receives input from the user, or it may use parameters received previously, or even by another application. Even if you don't pass parameters, there are request headers, cookies (if any), and user input can also be read from a database. Even if it looks like static data in the database, at some point it may have originated from some kind of a user, probably a legitimate (but rogue) one, or an external attacker, or it could have come from another application that writes to the same database (not a good practice anyway).

So in short, if the data you send back is really just static data (as in hard coded), that's not vulnerable, but there are many ways it can become dynamic, and from there it's your (ideally risk based) decision, what you protect against and what you trust.

The best practice is to encode everything by default to avoid mistakes. If you are sure that you trust the source of data that you want to insert into the DOM as HTML, that's fine. Threat modeling may help to discover what you should and should not trust, but in some cases it may also be obvious.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. Everything in your caveat I'm already aware of - the page isn't strictly static, but all the dynamic variables are properly escaped entries from Joomla's menu module used on the server, so they may as well be. I've basically been fretting that using innerHTML with AJAX was a bad idea and that somehow XSS could act like some kind of MITM attack if I wasn't careful; I can see now I've been fretting pointlessly.